# RestSharp get post data before sending

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have the following code using RestSharp.

```
var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);
request.AddQueryParameter("p1", GetNonce().ToString());
request.AddQueryParameter("p2", ApiKey);

if (parameters != null)
{
    foreach (var p in parameters)
        request.AddParameter(p.Key, p.Value);
}

string pathAndQuery = client.BuildUri(request).PathAndQuery;
string postData = ???
```

I can get the final Url with `client.BuildUri(request).PathAndQuery`. Is there a way to get the POST data that will be used for the query before executing the query?

Comment: An HTTP request is composed of many parts, such as header, body, etc.. What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: I want do see the body of the message

Comment: The key values you add, that is the body.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var requestParameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    parameters = this.restRequest.Parameters
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all parameters of a request from [RestRequest.Parameters](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/0ef81fd0a96149d8e1b73c0b2eeb6a7398681ae9/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L511).

In your code block access to `List<Parameter> Parameters` with `request.Parameters` and filter by `ParameterType` to get all post parameters.